# docker & docker-compose - Apache image with an option to switch between SSL Cert, self-signed, Let's Encryp or disabled

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I'm creating a docker image for Apache. I would like to configure SSL certs with an option to switch between different certificate provider.

**SSL Cert** (or) **Let's Encryp** (or) **Self Signed** (or) **Disable SSL altogether**

Any idea on how to accomplish that? Unfortunately cannot find any example out on the internet. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y update
RUN yum -y install httpd mod-ssl
RUN yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum
...
```

I want to be able to do something like this.

**Docker run:**

**SSL Cert:**

```
docker run -d -e sslCertType=sslCert 
              -v /etc/cert.crt:/etc/httpd/conf.d/cert.crt 
              -v /etc/intermediate.crt:/etc/httpd/conf.d/intermediate.crt
              -v /etc/passphrase.sh:/etc/httpd/conf.d/passphrase.sh 
                 apache
```

**LetsEncrpt:**

```
docker run -d -e sslCertType=letsEncrypt apache
```

**Self Signed:**

```
docker run -d -e sslCertType=selfSigned apache
```

**disabled:**

```
docker run -d apache
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just build 4 different images with different configuration and tag them correctly i.e.

apache:selfSigned

apache:sslCert

and then just run them accordingly i.e.:

```
docker run -d apache:selfSigned
```

Comment: Unfortunately this work for us. Apache is part of a package(tar file). We don't want to be maintain different package for each client.